# make container with forms mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-blade

Trying to make container with two form group side by side look mobile friendly. To make it put the left form under the other. Tried to change the width in container but that didn't work.

Here is the code:

hvertime.blade.php

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
<br>
<h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Times målinger </h2>
<hr>
     @if(Session::has('message'))
        <p style="color: green;">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
       @endif




    @if($errors->has())
        <ul>
            {{ $errors->first('badendeTime', '<li>:message</li>') }}
            {{ $errors->first('temp', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        </ul>
    @endif





    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/insertHT', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}

  <div class="form-group">

    <label  class="col-md-5 control-label">Basseng: </label>
    <div class="col-md-7">

     {{ Form::select('pool_id', $pools, Input::old('pool_id'), array('placeholder'=>'Basseng', 'class' => 'form-control' )) }} 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-md-7 control-label">Badende Per Time: </label>
    <div class="col-md-5" >
      {{ Form::text('T_Badende_per_Time', Input::old('T_Badende_per_Time'), array('placeholder'=>'', 'class' => 'form-control' ))  }}  
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-md-7 control-label">Temperatur: </label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
     {{ Form::text('T_Temperatur', Input::old('T_Temperatur'), array('placeholder'=>'', 'class' => 'form-control' )) }}  


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-5">
       {{ Form::submit('Lagre', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
    </div>
  </div>


      {{ Form::close() }}



     <div id="form-horizontal"> 

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/insertHT', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}

         <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="col-md-7 control-label">Luft-Temperatur: </label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
         {{ Form::text('T_Luft_Temperatur', Input::old('T_Luft_Temperatur'), array('placeholder'=>'', 'class' => 'form-control' )) }}  


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-7">
           {{ Form::submit('Lagre', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}



      </div>



     </div>
        </div>
```

main.css

```
.jumbotron {

    text-align: center; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: 1366px;
}

.form-group {



}


h2  {

    text-align: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    }

.container {
    min-height: 530px;
     /* set border styling */
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;  


    /* set border roundness */
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
     margin: auto auto auto;
    width: 900px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;   

}


.form-horizontal{
    float: left;   
}
```

Comment: do you think people care about what templating language you use server-side and is it relevant to your problem? no, so just paste the html ,not the php.

Comment: Sorry! The php file is html, its the view file in the MVC model.

Comment: Agreed but you could extract the rendered HTML if you want people to be able to help you debug easily. Also tagging with laravel and blade is probably unnecessary if the issue is not directly related. You just end up spamming these tags with unrelated questions.